# use tmpfs for mounting ~/.cache directory

Tags: mount, encryption, tmpfs

I am using Ubuntu 15.04, my home partition is encrypted. I was trying to use tmpfs for .cache directory . But don't know why its not working. Here is my fstab

```
tmpfs /var/log/ tmpfs defaults,noatime,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=1777,size=512M 0 0
tmpfs /home/prism/.cache/ tmpfs defaults,noatime,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=1777,size=100M 0 0
```

But my rest entry are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use /dev/shm (default tmpfs device on unix)

you can do something like this in your ~/.xprofile :

```
#!/bin/sh
rm -rf /dev/shm/${USER}cache
mkdir /dev/shm/${USER}cache
chmod 700 /dev/shm/${USER}cache
rm -rf /home/${USER}/.cache
ln -s /dev/shm/${USER}cache /home/${USER}/.cache
```